# Typesetting magazine style articles

Tags: two-column, templates

I am trying to compose a two column magazine style article (for a hobby) with callouts, multiple typefaces, etc. Are there examples of style files and class files that do something similar?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Do you have an image, or a link to one, showing the desired style you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This looks very broad to me, and therefore not a good fit for the TeX-sx format. Each area you ask about would make good questions, but some have already been covered.