# Designing Magazines in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-styles

How to design attractive magazines using LaTeX?Will **TikZ** be sufficient.What packages to include in the book class

Comment: Good question: You could also include attractive newsletters perhaps?

Comment: The `flowfram` package comes with some [sample files](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/samples/) that include some newsletter type of documents. There's also a [GUI-assisted version](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/manual/newstutorial.html).

Comment: using the page dimensions of the book class will yield an awfully small magazine; you'll at least need `geometry`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're going for here... of course you CAN design magazines in Latex, whether those are attractive for a general audience is questionable. In my head I'm comparing my average sci paper to The Sun, that doesn't really work ;)

Comment: I find this a perfect question but [beware](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127532/typesetting-magazine-style-articles).